# Uploading large data On Aws Spark EC2 Cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, upload

I am trying to upload a large text file (50.4GB). In my cluster I have four  **r3.2xlarge** instances each having 1x160 GB of SSD hard drive. After a while the upload stops. 
I have tried both WinSCP and FileZilla but neither of them was able to make it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you offer details as to why the upload stops? You might also try Putty.

Comment: In WinSCP I don't get any error message. In FileZilla I get something like "error during file transfer". Could you please tell me more about **PuTTY**